# Two NSMutableArrays sorted according objects of first one

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have two NSMutableArrays with NSString and NSNumber objects, more specific:

```
NSMutableArray * points; // NSNumber objects
NSMutableArray * players; //NSString objects
```

and i need to sort both of them according the objects of points. I try this [Order two NSMutableArrays based on one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688484/order-two-nsmutablearrays-based-on-one) but didn't help because of NSArray. I need to do this in NSMutableArrays. I sort points using this

```
NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
[points sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should introduce a Player Class

```
@interface Player : NSObject
@property(strong) NSString *name;
@property(strong) NSNumber *points;
@end
```

Instead of keeping the informations in seperated arrays, you would now have a Player object for each player and keep the point inside. Now put all the players in an array, that you can sort easily.

```
[players sortUsingComparator: ^(Player *p1, Player *p2){
    if (p1.points < p2.points)
        return NSOrderedAscending;   
    else if(p1.points > p2.points)
        return NSOrderedDescending 
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: +1 or at the very least put the related data into a dictionary and maintain an array of homogeneous dictionaries.

Comment: Absolutely, contain this into first class object