# Sort NSArray by another NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

```
NSArray *animals = @[@"Giraffe", @"Bear", @"Porcupine", @"Kangaroo"];
NSArray *likes = @[@"4", @"2", @"8", @"4"];
```

How do I order animals by likes?

Comment: The answers provided on the above linked duplicate question do not answer the question I posed. The 'duplicate' question does not ask how to handle situations where values are repeated, such as in my question with the value of @"4"

Comment: [Peter Hosey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8689662/603977) handles the issue of duplicate keys. If that still does not work for you, please [edit] this question to explain your problem in more detail.